# how to get country from ip in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ip, laravel-7

I have Creates custom Analytics Module, Where I can track the Visitor Activity, Here I used the Laravel Package "stevebauman/location" for getting Visitor Location.

The main issue is that, when I statically provide the IP to the Variable, this ip provided me the correct location. on the other hand, When I get IP dynamically. It just provide the IP

```
$visitor = request()->ip();
```

How Can I get country Name, Code, Postal Address from the IP in Laravel

```
$visitor = request()->ip();
    $traffic = PageVisits::where('ip_address', $visitor)->where('property_id', $id)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->first();
    if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->usertype == 'Admin'){
    
    }else{
        if (!$traffic) {

            $traffic = new PageVisits();
            $traffic->ip_address = $visitor;
            $traffic->property_id = $id;
            $position = Location::get('https://'.$visitor);
            $traffic->country = $position->countryName;
            $traffic->agency_id = $property->agency_id ?? '';
            $traffic->save();
        }
```

Comment: We use https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php and manually download the free maxmind db for that

Answer (score 0):

You Can Create Folder With service and but it >>>> I use apiStack

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class IpStack
{

    protected $key;

    protected $baseUrl = 'http://api.ipstack.com/';

    public function __construct($key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function get($ip)
    {
        // http://api.ipstack.com/(ip)?access_key=(key)
        $response = Http::baseUrl($this->baseUrl)
            ->get($ip, [
                'access_key' => $this->key,
            ]);

        return $response->json();
    }
}
```

for call  in controller

```
{
 $geoip = new IpStack(config('services.ipstack.key'));
            $response = $geoip->get(request()->ip());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Laravel 9.

Since you have this displaying location data already, It means you have everything installed and working fine. You only have to make a few changes.

The default behavior of the location service is affected by these lines of code in `config\location.php` file:

```php
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Localhost Testing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your running your website locally and want to test different
    | IP addresses to see location detection, set 'enabled' to true.
    |
    | The testing IP address is a Google host in the United-States.
    |
    */

    'testing' => [
        'ip' => '66.102.0.0',
        'enabled' => env('LOCATION_TESTING', true),
    ],
```

The comments before the code gives detailed explanation. Here 'enable' is already set to true.

Now, when you are on a live server and you want info on the current client that accesses your website, simply go to your `.env` file in the root folder of your application and add this line of code on a new line at the end of the file:

```php
LOCATION_TESTING=false
```

To test this in my controller, I simply put this in my `LocationController.php` file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;

class LocationController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $location = Location::get($request->ip);
        dd($location->countryName);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
"Nigeria" // app\Http\Controllers\CommentController.php:42
```

If I dump the `$location` variable instead (`dd($location`) while accessing my live server from my local PC, I get this:

```
Stevebauman\Location\Position {#1333 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/CommentController.php:42
  +ip: "177.120.78.226"
  +driver: "Stevebauman\Location\Drivers\IpApi"
  +countryName: "Nigeria"
  +countryCode: "NG"
  +regionCode: "RI"
  +regionName: "Rivers State"
  +cityName: "Port Harcourt"
  +zipCode: ""
  +isoCode: null
  +postalCode: null
  +latitude: "4.7731"
  +longitude: "7.0085"
  +metroCode: null
  +areaCode: "RI"
  +timezone: "Africa/Lagos"
}
```

so you can pick other information such as zipCode, cityName etc. from there as well.

**NOTE:** If you do this on a local server (localhost) after editing your `.env` file, the `$location` variable will return a boolean value of *false*. If you want to return to your testing setup, comment out the line you added to your `.env` file or simply change `LOCATION_TESTING=true`.